# How to input EOF in stdin in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, I wonder how to input EOF in stdin for R ?
For example, the function readLines() reads input lines from stdin, but how can tell it to stop ?

A rookie problem, and thanks for you attention.

PS. Problem solved. But I still cannot input EOF in the StatET (R plugin for eclipse). Any one has any solution ?

Comment: Could you find a solution for StatET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input is handled by the `readline` library common to other GNU project programs, and it commonly receives EOF when you press Ctrl-D.

Here is an example using [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (and I am not sure why every inout gets echoed back):

```
$ r -e 'print(summary(as.integer(readLines())))'
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
8
8                                                    ## I pressed Ctrl-D here
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     2.0     3.0     3.6     4.0     8.0 
$
```

Comment: But when I type input for readLines, pressinbg Ctrl-D gives apparently nothing, what's the problem ?

Comment: And I tried your example above, but nothing happens when I pressed Ctrl-D. I'm using RGui 2.13.0.

Comment: The Windows equivalent of Ctrl+D is Ctrl+Z

Comment: How to input Ctrl-D in StatET(R plugin for eclipse) ?

Comment: If you know the number of lines beforehand the `n` argument in `readLines` can come in handy.

Comment: Also, at least in my console, `Ctrl+D` only works while the line is still empty.