# Use stdin from within R studio

Tags: linux, r, stdin, rstudio

When I try the following:

```
f<-file("stdin")
lines<-readLines(f)
```

from within R-studio on Ubuntu I can input text but unable to terminate it. Ctr+C/D, random hitting keyboard won't help. It simply hangs

I only found the followin so far 
[How to input EOF in stdin in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734304/how-to-input-eof-in-stdin-in-r)
but no help there - had to kill R-studio.

Anybody have explanation what is wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734304/how-to-input-eof-in-stdin-in-r

Answer (score 8):

Presumably, Rstudio is redirecting stdin, so that it cannot be properly accessed as `"stdin"` or `"/dev/stdin"` any longer. However, `stdin()` still works.

I was still unable to actually type Ctrl+D. But it is possible to read a fixed number of lines:

```
> a <- readLines(stdin(), n=2)
Hello
World
> a 
[1] "Hello" "World"
```

I've also discovered a hack that may help for interactive debugging. Let's say, you have at most 10 lines in your manual examples. Then you can do

```
> a <- readLines(stdin(), n=10)
abc
def
ghi

# and now just keep pressing ENTER
...

> a <- a[a != ""]
> a
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

If you run the same code in an environment where Ctrl+D is available, it also properly terminates the input.

**Caveats:** but `stdin()` does not work with `Rscript`: you'd have to switch back to `file("stdin")`. Furthermore, in some environments, if you use `readLines` with `n=1` to read the file line-by-line, you may end up reopening the file and getting the first line every time. It seems that putting everything into a file and reading the whole file at once with e.g. `read.table` is a much more robust way of developing with Rstudio.

Comment: I came here, because some silly website chooses to use stdin for its statics code a day.  Day 1 is figuring out how to get stdin to work rather than simply putting some input data in an array.  Anyway thanks for the explanation. I appreciate it.