# My attempt to use a "connection" while trying to read in input causes R to freeze or crash

Tags: r, rstudio

Sorry, but the terminology I use in the title may not be used correctly.  Whenever I try to run this code, it seems like it is trying to run it but never completes the command.  When I click the stop command sign (red), it doesn't do anything.  I cannot close out of R.  So why is this taking forever to run?

```
con <- file('stdin', open = 'r')

inputs <- readLines(con)
```

Comment: Try `readLines(stdin())`

Comment: this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191232/use-stdin-from-within-r-studio

Comment: @RADO, I'll award the bounty to the answer you accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working in RStudio, you need to use `readLines(stdin())` rather than `readLines(file('stdin'))`, though you can use either if running R in the terminal.

However, there is also an issue from not specifying the number of lines of input since you are using RStudio. When reading input from stdin, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> signals the end of input. However, if you are doing this from RStudio rather than from the terminal [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is unavailable](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200656347-Is-there-a-way-to-emulate-Ctrl-D-terminate-stdin-), so without specifying the lines of input there is no way to terminate the reading from stdin.

So, if you are running R from the terminal, your code will work, and you signal the end of input via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. If you must work from RStudio, you can still use `readLines(stdin())` [if you know the number of lines of input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936135/8386140); e.g.,

```
> readLines(stdin(), n=2)
Hello
World
[1] "Hello" "World"
```

An alternate workaround is to use `scan()`, e.g.:

```
> scan(,'')
1: Hello
2: World
3: 
Read 2 items
[1] "Hello" "World"
```

(On the third line I just pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> to terminate input). The advantage there is that you don't need to know the number of lines of input beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio has a somewhat indirect connection to R (At least [4 years ago](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660746-reading-stdin-in-console-mayhem-ensues) it redirected stdin to nowhere).  It is probably, for our purposes, embedded.  This is probably part of why `stdin()` can work when paired with readLines (It creates a terminal connection rather than a file connection).  @duckmayr's `scan()` solution is quite nice and is documented to be the kind of thing that works in this situation...

> the name of a file to read data values from. If the specified file is
>   "", then input is taken from the keyboard (or whatever stdin() reads
>   if input is redirected or R is embedded).

In case you want to consider a blank input 'okay', you can also loop over getting the data from a single line with some sentinel value, i.e. thing that makes the loop stop (here 'EOF').

```
input <- function() {
  entry <- ''
  while (!any(entry == "EOF")) {
    entry <- c(readline(), entry)  
  }
  return(entry[-1])
}
```